# Javascript for modal and passing hidden input is not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out what happened but this worked in my fiddle previously and now it doesn't.

Very basic for the most part, but I have a text area and a link that opens a modal. WHen the modal opens I want to save the content of the textarea as the value of the hidden input but I'm also trying to echo the content in the modal for confirmation. It was working fine but now the modal loads sucessfully yet it doesn't echo the content or give the alert with the content. It seems like the javascript is just not working for some reason

The biggest issue is that it saves a record for the content of the textarea in my database but there's no actual content

HTML

```
<textarea class="original" name="fullText" id="mytextarea3"></textarea>

<p><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal">Save page</a></p>
<!-- Opens modal -->

<form action="addPage.php" method="post">
<div class="modal fade saveModal" id="my_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="savePageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">

                <!-- This should house the content of the textarea -->
                <input type="hidden" id="new" value="">
                <!-- This should echo the content of the textarea for confirmation -->
                <h2 id="demo"></h2>

            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="Save Page">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  var original = $(".original").val();

  $("#new").val(original);
  $("#demo").html(original);

  alert($("#new").val());
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

Sources -

```
 <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="src/ytv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>
```

UPDATE 2:

whole page code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Template One</title>

                <style type="text/css">
                    @import "style.css";
                    html,
                    body {
                      height: 100%;
                      overflow: hidden;
                    }

                    .my-container {
                      display: flex;
                      flex-direction: column;
                      height: 100%;
                    }

                    .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
                    .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
                      background-color: #929292  ;
                      color: white;
                      text-align: center;
                    }

                    .my-container>.middle {
                      flex-grow: 1;
                      padding:30px;
                      background-image: url('images/bg6.jpg');
                      background-size: cover;
                    }

                    .my-container>.middle>* {
                    }

                    #clock{
                        /*background-color:#333;*/
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size:40px;
                        text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #fff;
                        color:#fff;
                    }
                    #clock span {
                        color:#fff;
                        font-size:40px;
                        position:relative;

                    }
                    #date {
                        margin-top: -10px;
                        letter-spacing:3px;
                        font-size:20px;
                        font-family:arial,sans-serif;
                        color:#fff;
                    }

                    .buttonContainer {
                      display: flex;
                      flex-direction: column;
                      justify-content: center;
                    }
                </style>

              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
              <link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
              <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


              <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>


            </head>
            <body onload="startTime()">

            <?php include("menu.php");?>

            <?php startblock('article') ?>

                <!-- TITLE BLOCK -->
                <div class="container-fluid title-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="page-header">
                            <h2>Create A New Page</h2>      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3"><a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Choose Page Background</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <hr>

                <div class="container-fluid my-container">

                    <!-- Background image modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Choose an image:</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row top">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 align-self-center">
                                <div id="clockdate">
                                  <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
                                    <div id="clock"></div>
                                    <div id="date"></div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row middle">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth">
                        <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
                              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row bottom">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="marquee"><h2>This is a test</h2></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div>

                <p><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal">Save page</a></p>    


                <form action="addPage.php" method="post">
                <div class="modal fade" id="my_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="savePageLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="savePageLabel">Page Details:</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="fullText" value> -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="new" name="page_content" value="">
                                <p id="demo"></p>
                                </br>
                                <label for="addTitle">Page Title:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="addTitle" name="addTitle">

                                </input>

                                <label for="areaSelect">Select An Area</label>
                                <select name="displayId" class="form-control" id="areaSelect">

                                    <!-- <option value=""></option> -->
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>

                                </select>

                                <label for="durationSet">Set A Duration (in seconds)</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="durationSet" name="durationSet">

                                </input>

                                <label for="expirationSelect">Set Expiration Date/Time</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="datepick input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker" name="datePicker" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" name="Save Page">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
              $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
                var original = $(".original").val();

                $("#new").val(original);
                $("#demo").html(original);

                alert($("#new").val());
                console.log(original);
              });
            });
            </script>



              <script type="text/javascript">
              tinymce.init({
                selector: '#mytextarea3',
                height: 500,
              theme: 'modern',
              plugins: 'print preview fullpage paste searchreplace autolink directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount spellchecker imagetools media  link contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
              toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
              image_advtab: true,
              templates: [
                { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
              ],
              content_css: [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
              ]
              });
              </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.datepick').each(function(){
                  $(this).datetimepicker({
                   icons: {
                                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                            }
                });
                });
            });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var $modalLeft = $('#leftFiftyModal').modal({
                show: false
            });
            $('.leftFifty').on('click', function() {
                $modalLeft.modal('show');
            });

            var $modalRight = $('#rightFiftyModal').modal({
                show: false
            });
            $('.rightFifty').on('click', function() {
                $modalRight.modal('show');
            });

            var $modalFull = $('#fullModal').modal({
                show: false
            });
            $('.fullWidth').on('click', function() {
                $modalFull.modal('show');
            });

            </script>

            <script>
            !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','weatherwidget-io-js');
            </script>

             <script src="js/clock.js"></script>

             <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.marquee').marquee({
                    duration: 30000,
                    gap:30,
                });
             </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#exampleModal .modal-body img').click(function() {
              const src = $(this).attr("src");
              $('.my-container > .middle').css("background-image", `url(${src})`);
              jQuery.noConflict();
              $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
            });

             </script>

            <?php endblock() ?>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Can you add the fiddle back? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No console errors, but i did a console.log(first) and when I preform the action with the console open it just adds a blank line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/4197/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.

Comment: I just did it - I typed "test" into the text field, clicked 'get modal'. It showed an alert box with "test" in it and then the modal appeared with "test" as content. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes the fiddle is working but what I'm doing on my live page(code above) is not working. The only main difference is I have the whole code block wrapped in a form but I feel like there's a javascript conflict or something

Comment: Just the simple things - are you sure you've added jQuery and bootstrap and its dependencies? All that good stuff?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/b9fm4287/2/

Comment: @dgig I understand the double check, I have. I'm adding them to the question now in the order they are on the page

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm not sure why it works in the fiddle and not my page though

Comment: Have you checked the browser console ?

Comment: I just threw it into a code pen in debug mode and it works as well - https://s.codepen.io/dmgig/debug/mjrRpO take a look at the source and see what's different. Something is screwy in your browser or cache or something. I only added the bootstrap css. (I also closed off your script tag but that's probably an oversight).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yep and it's not showing anything at all, good or bad

Comment: show us the whole page code please

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I've added it now

Comment: You mention that it previously worked, what have you changed?  Was it lots of things?  That's my guess.  Maybe go back to what you previously had, and try changing one little bit at a time.  This might reveal where things finally go wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is because the textarea is used with tinymce.. as this is in no fiddle or codepin till now, it could be the problem that tinymce transforms your textarea into something else where the real value is saved.. try to make right click on the textarea on your life code and take a look if the your input gets written into something else then .original

Comment: That would make sense because the only other difference between my page and the fiddle is that the fiddle is just using plain textarea

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp what do you mean about right click?

Comment: yes and if you see here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/ tinymce makes a lot of divs out of the textarea, so that will be the problem i think ;)

Comment: right click and q - i dont know the english words in the browser ;)

Comment: try to get your value with: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); or with this: tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var original = $('.original').val();

Comment: Oh like inspecting it, I see. I did that and you're right, it turns into a log that eventually puts my content into body id tinymce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176276/discussion-between-christopher-supertramp-and-tom-n).